# Vuforia Cloud Database Target with custom content

Tags: vuforia

Thanks to Apple I now have to migrate from Metaio to Vuforia.

What I mostly used on Metaio was its cloud service and Creator in order to upload a target and content attached to it into my own channel.

Now I just started reading Vuforia documentation but I can't find anything about an online interface or a program like Creator in order to attach content to my target..

I can only upload a target, and then what should I do in order to attach content to it (for example start playing a video when the target get recognized) ?